# I have 2 streaming sources of data, how can I raise a flag when one does not match the other?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, comparison, streaming

I have 2 sources of streaming data; A and B.

Let's say both sources spit out a new integer every 400 micro seconds.

Is it possible to compare these two sources of data simultaneously, and make sure that the integers read from the two sources are equal and raise a flag when they are not? Is such a thing possible in C#?

If so, is it only possible through use of multi-threading?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, just implement a queue that wait for the two notifications of stream A and stream B, when the stream A produces an integer, and B, you compare and set the flags that you need.

Without multi-threading probably impossible, the only solution for single-thread that i've in mind is pooling the 2 sources of streams.

For the queue is pretty easy to implement via BeginReads (assuming that u have streams), and locks for exclusion